# autolayout for custom table view cell

Tags: objective-c, ios-autolayout

I just have a image in a CustomCell xib. And I am setting the top constraint and leading constraint to the superview and height and width for the image.
But the cell height is not getting set in table view resulting in image coming out of cell giving warning 'Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead..'

for the testing purpose , if in CustomCell.xib I have a empty custom cell and I set row height as 180 and run it. then also its not setting the same height in table view . why is it happening. how is auto layouts set for that image.

Comment: Add bottom constraint for the imageview

Comment: share screen shots and code please.